# Custom Object Sorting v/s Integer Sorting - Complexity differences?

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity

How substantial can be the difference between the complexities of sorting an integer array v/s sorting a custom object array (with hundreds/thousands of fields) on the basis of 1 integer field?

Note :- By complexities I mean the time /space complexity & it's impact on execution time in the above given scenario

Example :- We have Custom Object with the structure below:

```
structure LargeData {
int Identifier
string Name
string Description
.....1000+ fields similarly
}
```

Now if we have a 25 objects of this structure in an array, & we try to sort it based on the int field "Identifier", what is the impact on the computation time, & space required when we compare it to a simple integer array?

Does it have a noticeable impact of the performance?

Comment: Do you have an example of two different algorithms you're trying to compare? If not, what is motivating this question? Specifically, why do you think that there would be a complexity difference between a sort of integers vs a sort of objects by a field?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Welbog By complexity I meant the performance impacts related to sorting time. I have updated the question with an example. My motive here is to know whether this performance impact is manageable & whether I should be worried when iterating through large structures just to sort them?